# Measuring time difference between networked devices

Tags: networking

I'm adding networked multiplayer to a game I've made. When the server sends an update packet to the client, I include a timestamp so that the client knows exactly when that information is valid. However, the server computer and the client computer might have their clocks set to different times (maybe even just a few seconds difference), so the timestamp from the server needs to be translated to the client's local time.

So, I'd like to know the best way to calculate the time difference between the server and the client. Currently, the client pings the server for a time stamp during initialization, takes note of when the request was sent and when it was answered, and guesses that the time stamp was generated roughly halfway along the journey. The client also runs 10 of these trials and takes the average.

But, the problem is that I'm getting different results over repeated runs of the program. Within each set of 10, each measurement rarely diverges by more than 400 milliseconds, which might be acceptable. But if I wait a few minutes between each run of the program, the resulting averages might disagree by as much as 2 seconds, which is not acceptable.

Is there a better way to figure out the difference between the clocks of two networked devices? Or is there at least a way to tweak my algorithm to yield more accurate results?

Details that may or may not be relevant: The devices are iPod Touches communicating over Bluetooth. I'm measuring pings to be anywhere from 50-200 milliseconds. I can't ask the users to sync up their clocks. :)

---

Update: With the help of the below answers, I wrote an objective-c class to handle this. I posted it on my blog: http://scooops.blogspot.com/2010/09/timesync-was-time-sink.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I recently took a one-hour class on this and it wasn't long enough, but I'll try to boil it down to get you pointed in the right direction.  Get ready for a little algebra.

Let s equal the time according to the server.  Let c equal the time according to the client.  Let d = s - c.  d is what is added to the client's time to correct it to the server's time, and is what we need to solve for.

First we send a packet from the server to the client with a timestamp.  When that packet is received at the client, it stores the difference between the given timestamp and its own clock as t1.

The client then sends a packet to the server with its own timestamp.  The server sends the difference between the timestamp and its own clock back to the client as t2.

Note that t1 and t2 both include the "travel time" t of the packet plus the time difference between the two clocks d.  Assuming for the moment that the travel time is the same in both directions, we now have two equations in two unknowns, which can be solved:

```
t1 = t - d
t2 = t + d
t1 + d = t2 - d
d = (t2 - t1)/2
```

The trick comes because the travel time is not always constant, as evidenced by your pings between 50 and 200 ms.  It turns out to be most accurate to use the timestamps with the minimum ping time.  That's because your ping time is the sum of the "bare metal" delay plus any delays spent waiting in router queues.  Every once in a while, a lucky packet gets through without any queuing delays, so you use that minimum time as the most repeatable time.

Also keep in mind that clocks run at different rates.  For example, I can reset my computer at home to the millisecond and a day later it will be 8 seconds slow.  That means you have to continually readjust d.  You can use the slope of various values of d computed over time to calculate your drift and compensate for it in between measurements, but that's beyond the scope of an answer here.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for. It's not entirely clear to me yet why that's better than my original method (although I believe that it is), but I'll post back here when I try it out. I don't think I'll need to adjust d throughout a gaming session, but it shouldn't be hard to do if I need to. Thanks again!

Comment: This has worked really well. I found that if I always take the smallest (i.e., most negative) t1 and t2 values, it's the same as taking the smallest pings, so it converges on the correct offset. 

I have 
    t1 = client stamp - server stamp
and
    t2 = server stamp - client stamp

Also, I've found out that iphones drift pretty significantly! Within a half an hour, the actual offset between two devices might change by as much as half a second. I verified this with clock programs that contact NTP servers.

Comment: See also, [Clock synchronization algorithm | Network Time Protocol - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm) – this includes the said equation, a similar algorithm, and a fancy diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm will not be much more accurate unless you can use some statistical methods. First of all, 10 is probably not sufficient. The first and simplest change would be to gather 100 transit time samples and toss out the x longest and shortest.

Another thing to add would be that both clients send their own timestamp in each packet. Then you can also calculate how different their clocks are and check the average difference between the clocks.

You can also check up on STNP and NTP implementations specifically, as these protocols do this specifically.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll try the algorithm given by the answer above, and take your advice on using multiple samples.