# Current Android time in nanosecond

Tags: java, android, time

I want to measure transmission time of two android phones using Socket in Client and Server,so I thought the easiest way is to put

```
System.NanoTime()
```

After sending from Client then after receive from server then subtract them to get the exact time.
but I got different time on each phone and when subtract them I've got strange long number ( the first small phone with xxxxxx E12, and the other phone xxxxxx E13 number)
so how can i get the number in readable format, and is there different result if i use different kind of phones?
thanks

Comment: You want to measure the time difference between two devices in nanoseconds? Your data will be *very* noisy due to natural [clock drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift) between the devices.

Comment: this is mathematics....if you get a value like E12, it means to put the point 12 positions to the right to get the value. So you get the correct values, but the device couldn´t show it with that much numbers. I don´t think that it is possible to get the same values by sending to server and evaluate. With nanoseconds, there is too much time between these steps...

Comment: Also, from the [javadoc on nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) - "This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin." - **you can't compare them across devices**

Comment: I understand that, but is there another way to measure the transmission time?

Comment: It's not easy - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755208/measuring-time-difference-between-networked-devices as a starting point

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you only need to calculate transmission time which is the time that request-response take.

So instead of returning nano, what you can do is calling `currentTimeMillis()`, before establishing the connection:

```
long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then after you get a response use:

```
long fTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = fTime - sTime;
```

> how can i get the number in readable format?

```
DateFormat.getInstance().format(elapsedTime);
```

The above can be applied on `System.NanoTime()`, whether you want to use nano or milli its a question of (accuracy Vs. performance) if you want an extremely precise measurements and its more important to you than performance then use nano.

Of-course you gotta keep in mind that elapsedTime will vary from while to while as there are much more to it than a good implementation , so don't expect it to be constant.

**Edit 1:**

> I use DateFormat with nanoTime cause i need very small time but i got
>   1/1/1970 3:28 am !! all I need is like (123455 nanosecond time
>   transmit)

And that's why I've used `System.currentTimeMillis` in my example as nano time form would be 10^-9 seconds, to get a larger granularity use `System.currentTimeMillis()` Or you can simply convert nano to seconds using:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(elapsedTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

If you don't want to use `TimeUnit` just divide the number that you get by `1000000000`.

Comment: I use DateFormat with nanoTime cause i need very small time but i got 1/1/1970 3:28 am !! all I need is like (123455 nanosecond time transmit)